# Как обновить только определенную часть страницы

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Как обновить только определенную часть страницы, не перезагружая всю страницу?
Проблема в том, что реализовано следующим образом:

При нажатии на определенную ссылку подгружается из нового файла html код, а предыдущая "программа" сворачивается. Т.к. эти две программы - это терминал и кодовый редактор важно, чтобы написанное в них сохранялось, но этого не происходит, т.к. при открытии нового окна, старое удаляется из кода, как сделать так, чтобы оно не удалялось из кода, пока не нажмешь на определенную кнопку "закрыть"?

Это все вставляется в один и тот же тег section.

Comment: Добавь в вопросе свой код обновления

Comment: http://floomby.ru/s2/rWD9VW
http://floomby.ru/s2/MWD9Vr

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ залейте свой код сюда (и вам будет проще ответить, и пользователям ещё каким то вдруг понадобится)

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/